# Maintaining source IP while forwarding port from one host to another, but there is a small issue

Tags: linux, networking, routing, port-forwarding, iptables

I am using this tunnel approach:

https://superuser.com/a/1357450/972858

to forward a port N from x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y. Its working perfectly and destination y.y.y.y is able to see the actual source IP address. But there is one small issue. x.x.x.x:N can be accessed from everywhere but not from y.y.y.y itself. I am not sure why but I unable to telnet x.x.x.x:N from y.y.y.y.

Please help.

Comment: Probably the same issue as mentioned: hairpin NAT is necessary.

Comment: Thanks @grawity for your quick response and your solution to the mentioned question. As I stated, it works beautifully from everywhere except y.y.y.y (destination) cannot telnet the forwarded port N on x.x.x.x.

Everywhere -> x.x.x.x:N -> y.y.y.y is working is y.y.y.y is able to see the actual source IP.

But if the connection is initiated from y.y.y.y itself:

y.y.y.y -> x.x.x.x:N is unable to connect. That is the only issue. Is there a workaround for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work for the exactly same reason as why port-forwarding within the same LAN doesn't generally work. In other words, it's a hairpin-NAT situation. (Imagine the tunnel as if it were simply a local LAN network.)

The tunnel itself may be working fine – the packet reaches X, gets NATed, and arrives back at Y. However, because Y sees the original sender as being *local*, the response does not go through X and therefore X cannot undo the NAT. As a result, addresses in the response do not match addresses in the original packet, and Y (as the original initiator) cannot find a matching connection for the response it just received.

Try adding a `-t nat -I PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x --dport N -j REDIRECT` rule to iptables to handle this case – it should catch the outgoing packets without having to involve X at all.

Comment: Thanks @grawity I added the following on y.y.y.y:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT

But no go.

Comment: iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport N -j REDIRECT works but should I be using that instead of PREROUTING ?

Comment: Ah, yes, for connections initiated by the same system, OUTPUT should be the correct one.