# Iptables transparent port forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, routing, port-forwarding, iptables

My question is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1357440/) question, but I don't seem to get the answer to work.

I have: Centos 8 Cloud VPS which I wish to use as transparent proxy to my game server, and my physical game server.

Both have static public IPs, and the second one is behind NAT, so I wasn't able to properly set up the GRE tunnel.

Let's assume Cloud VPS public IP is `x.x.x.x`, and the `y.y.y.y` is my physical game server public IP. `y.y.y.y` is also my home router IP and I don't want people to know it, so I came up with idea of using `x.x.x.x`'s iptables NAT to forward port `9001` to `y.y.y.y`. But now I can't see users' real IP address. So I made a simpliest OpenVPN cipherless site-to-site tunnel (Cloud is `192.168.254.1`, game server is `192.168.254.2`) and used these lines from the answer I was talking about in the beginning (used them on a game server):

```
ip route add default via 192.168.254.1 dev tun0 table 1111
ip rule add pref 1000 from 192.168.254.2 lookup 1111
```

And indeed it *did* work for a while, I was getting user's real IP instead of bloody `192.168.254.1`, but after I rebooted both servers to make sure that everything will still work after a reboot, I can't get it back to work no matter what.

What can I do to make this work again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iptables forwarding port/s to a external IP transparently (remote end should see the actual source IP)](https://superuser.com/questions/1357440/iptables-forwarding-port-s-to-a-external-ip-transparently-remote-end-should-see)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, as I said in the beginning, it does not anymore.